# How to change wordpress registration url

Tags: wordpress

Generally, wordpress registration  url is siteurl/wp-login.php?action=register
I want to change it to siteurl/register . How to do it?
Need Help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127636/change-register-url-on-wp-login-page

Comment: Sjors sir not working :( says fatal error 

Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_filter()

Comment: actually the plug in author did not updated  it what to do?

This plugin hasn't been updated in over 2 years. It may no longer be maintained or supported and may have compatibility issues when used with more recent versions of WordPress.

Comment: What plugin are you talking about? You don't need a plugin to change the URL. I think this comment will work: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/154717/66033

add_filter() is a default WordPress function, so if it can't be found you're using it in the wrong place or haven't installed WordPress properly: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but if you are using Apache as your webserver, you could use mod_rewrite rules to do this. It doesn't actually move the registration to a new URL, but it will make example.com/register point to example.com/wp-login.php?action=register

Something like:

```
Redirect 301 /register https://exmple.com/wp-login.php?action=register
```

I've not tested that but it looks correct.

HTH,

=C=

Comment: Sir not working. Besides i want to create a new page and i want this new page should be the same as 

https://siteurl/wp-login.php?action=register

Answer (score 0):

You can use wordpress plugin for that
https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/